# Изменение данных из firebase при смене языке в приложении

Tags: kotlin, firebase

Как реализовать функционал изменения данных когда меняю языке в приложении. Мне нужно поменять данные из firebase. Допустим я храню в firebase два описания места на русском и Английском, меняю язык в настройках приложения и данные должны подгружаться из таблицы en и меняться. Как это сделать? Очень важно для меня тк это функция в моем дипломе..